# AttributeError: 'class' object has no attribute 'rect'

Tags: python, class, pygame

I have this class:

```
class Comet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def ___init___(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.image = pygame.Surface((100,250))
    self.image.fill(cometL)
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.y = 800
    self.rect.x = 100
def update(self):
    self.rect.y -= 1+2*speed
def reset(self):
    self.rect.x = randint(0,700)
    self.rect.y = randint(1000,2000)
```

I try to use it here:

```
    comet1  = Comet()
    comet1.rect.x = 100
    comet1.rect.y = 800
    comets.add(comet1)
```

But when i do I get this error:

File "", line 36, in 
    comet1.rect.x = 100

AttributeError: 'comet' object has no attribute 'rect'

Even though the class does (I think, i'm kinda new to classes)

Comment: use `__init__`, not `___init___` (yours had 2 extra underscores)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your definition for `__init__` is wrong. You used three underscores (`___init___`), so this function is not called during instantiation of the class.

This means that the line `self.rect = self.image.get_rect()` isn't called and so there is no `rect` attribute.

Comment: Thanks. I knew it had to be something small like this.